# Displaying rational numbers using Mathjax

Tags: mathjax

Do you know why when I write:

```
`1/2`
```

It shows it as a fraction (1 is above 2). But when I write:

```
\begin{align} 10x &= 5 \\ x &= 1/2 \end{align}
```

It shows the 1/2 as written (next to each other).

(I use Mathjax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first form uses the AsciiMath preprocessor:

> By default, the asciimath2jax preprocessor defines the back-tick (`)
>   as the delimiters for mathematics in AsciiMath format.

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/asciimath.html#asciimath-delimiters

The latter uses the LaTex preprocessor syntax, and therefore you must write something like this:

```
 \begin{align} 10x &= 5 \\ x &= \frac{1}{2} \end{align}
```

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering